# Changing Online Player Playlist Using Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I am embedding a mp3 flash player on my TEST SITES, but the problem is the mp3 flash player it use playlist to play the mp3 files, and it use one playlist at a time, and i have many playlists.

Can someone help with script (Javascript, Jquery) so that user can select which playlist to play, from a dropdown list??

example html code:

```
<form action="#">
<select id="playlists" onchange="playlist();">
<option value="//sunnah.wen.ru/3/1.xml">Playlist 1</option> 
<option value="//sunnah.wen.ru/3/2.xml">Playlist 2</option> 
<option value="//sunnah.wen.ru/3/3.xml">Playlist 3</option> 
<option value="//sunnah.wen.ru/3/4.xml">Playlist 4</option> 
<option value="//sunnah.wen.ru/3/5.xml">Playlist 5</option> 
<option value="//sunnah.wen.ru/3/6.xml">Playlist 6</option> 
<option value="//sunnah.wen.ru/3/7.xml">Playlist 7</option> 
<option value="//sunnah.wen.ru/3/8.xml">Playlist 8</option> 
<option value="//sunnah.wen.ru/3/9.xml">Playlist 9</option> 
<option value="//sunnah.wen.ru/3/10.xml">Playlist 10</option>

</form>
```

the mp3 player code is:

```
<embed allowscriptaccess="never" src="http://sunnah.wen.ru/3/sunna4u.swf" menu="false" quality="high" width="300" height="300" name="index" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" flashvars="playList=http://sunnah.wen.ru/3/home.xhtml&ShowPlaylist=1&ShowEQ=1&firstTrack=1&initVol=100" wmode="transparent" /></embed>
```

the part that says: `playList=http://sunnah.wen.ru/3/home.xhtml` is the url to the playlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using a jQuery plugin called jQuery SWFObject:

http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/examples

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3KZD8/

```
$(function () {
    //initialize
    $("#player").flash({
        swf: 'http://sunnah.wen.ru/3/sunna4u.swf',
        height: 300,
        flashvars: {
            playList: "http://sunnah.wen.ru/3/home.xhtml",
            ShowPlaylist: 1,
            ShowEQ: 1,
            firstTrack: 1,
            initVol: 100
        }
    });

    //on change
    $("#playlists").change(function () {
        $("#player").flash({
            swf: 'http://sunnah.wen.ru/3/sunna4u.swf',
            height: 300,
            flashvars: {
                playList: "http:" + $(this).val(),
                ShowPlaylist: 1,
                ShowEQ: 1,
                firstTrack: 1,
                initVol: 100
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: this is exactly what i need, i  appreciate it jazakallah bi khair

Comment: No problem brother, if you need any help with this quran site, let me know I'll be happy to help